# Unstaged changes in Eclipse, but no changes in git

Tags: java, eclipse, git

When I change something in my repository I see some "Unstaged Changes" in Eclipse, but when I use git at the same time, it tells me that there are not any updates in my repository.
Why is that?
Should I change or configure something to see changes at the same time?
Or is that normal behavior?

Comment: what do you mean by `when i use git at the same time`? What is the command that you have used and its output? `git status`?

Comment: If you modify a file and save it, git should definitely show you that you have changes that have not been staged yet (unless you modified a file which is ignored by git). For example when you run `git status` you should see all modified files. Are you using git commandline client or some GUI client?

Comment: Exactly, I use "git status" as a command.I use git commandline client.

Comment: for example i add some files directly into repository by Eclipse and i see these changes in Eclipse, but git doesn't show me !

Comment: Can you try to add a file with the command line and see if it appears in Eclipse?

Comment: I presume `git status` responds with `nothing to commit, working directory clean`? Maybe a stupid question, but are you sure you run the `git status` command in the correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me many times, 
apparently there is a bug on git client in Eclipse

What do i do, and helped me:

> Try to stage the files and then unstage them via Eclipse

after that those files disappear form the unstaged area in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if any of the files are inadvertently checked in with a character case inconsistencies in the path.

You might need to do something like:

```
git mv Path/file.c path/file.c
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right cick on project. Go to: Team -> Synchronize workspace.
2. Click Yes on change prespective dialog box. You should see the list
   of changes on left hand side with > symbol.
3. Right click on project and click overwrite. This will prompt to if
   you want to overwrite the local changes.
4. Click Yes.

This will remove the local changes and you will no longer see the unwanted unstaged changes during git staging.